# Resize table using Listobjects not working

Tags: excel, vba, resize, datacolumn

I have a table in Sheet 2 with a name "MyTable". Number of rows of that table changes each time depending on the data. I would like to clear the contents of the table and resize it using a macro so that it has only two rows- a title row, and an empty row.

Table title row is from B5 until K5.

I tried the below code, it clears the table contents and resizes, however, does not resize as desired. It resizes, without clearing the table borders in column C.

Any help is really appreciated.

```
Sub Table_Resize()

Dim rng as Range 

Sheet2.Select
Range("MyTable").ClearContents
        
Set rng = Range("MyTable[#All]").Resize(2, 10)
Sheet2.ListObjects("MyTable").Resize rng

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please do share what's wrong with a simple `Sheet2.ListObjects("MyTable").DataBodyRange.Delete`?

Comment: @VBasic2008, I tried that and got the error "Subscript out of range".

Comment: `Subscript out of range` will happen if your table isn't on the sheet with the _codename_ `Sheet2`.  Reference the correct sheet and it will work - providing the DatabodyRange has data otherwise it will throw `Object Variable or With block variable not set`.... so check DatabodyRange is not nothing first.

Comment: Is it definitely a listobject type table?  Hard to tell as you've selected the last cell so can't see the table handle.  You have the _Table Design_ ribbon when a cell in the table is selected?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, Thanks for trying to help me. I was trying multiple options. Apparently there was some problem with the table itself. I redid the whole table in a new sheet and it seems to work fine. There was no problem with the macro codes that I was using.

Comment: Since you have fixed your workbook, could you now share what's wrong with a simple `Sheet2.ListObjects("MyTable").DataBodyRange.Delete`?

Comment: @VBasic2008, I am not trying to delete the rows because below that table there is some content which is always there. That content and the table go in an email. I have a different macro for that. So I am just looking to clear the table content and resize the table. The below codes in Answer section- Clearing the contents and then resizing worked for me. Thanks so much for your time trying to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do is to delete the all rows.

```
Sub Table_ClearContents_Resize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim ol As ListObject: Set ol = ws.ListObjects("MyTable")
    
    ' Delete table contents
    ol.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    
    ' Resize table
    ol.Resize Range(ol.HeaderRowRange.Resize(2).Address)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: `Set ol = Nothing` is not necessary.

Comment: @BigBen, I just put it there because the variable is local and to save resources. If it were global, I would not do it. Why do you say that is not necessary?

Comment: @ElioFernandes, Thanks for taking time to look at my question. I am not trying to delete the rows because below that table there is some content which is always there. That content and the table go in an email. I have a different macro for that. So I am just looking to clear the table content and resize the table.

Comment: @Seema. Can you post an image on how it should be after clearing the contents of the table and doing the resize?

Comment: I just updated the code to resize the table.

Comment: @ElioFernandes, I have attached the screenshot of the table to my post above.  Could you please take a look?
Also, I tried your codes, it still does the same thing. It resizes the table, but the borders in one of the columns stays. Rest everything goes well.

Comment: @Seema. Look at the picture I posted. Tell me if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: @ElioFernandes, Exactly!! That's what I wanted. I was trying multiple options. Apparently there was some trouble with the table itself. I redid the whole table in a new sheet and it seems to work fine. Looks like there was no problem with the macro codes that I was using . Thanks so much trying to help me out with this. In case you see anything wrong with the code that I am using, could you please let me know? Thanks again.

Comment: @Seema. Your code works although it's not dynamic if you need to add or remove new columns. Try the code I just updated. Try to run it deleting or adding columns.

Comment: @ElioFernandes, your code worked very well for me. Thank you very much! Really appreciate your time!